# Problem assigning dynamic masks for loop

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm loading 8 thumbnails via XML, placing in a sprite, and spacing them out with a helper grid class. This part works. What does not work is when I try to assign a mask to each of these (using a simpleRectangle class I made) I appear to only be assigning a mask to the last image. Am I doing something wrong with 'imageLoader.mask = _mask;' ?

My ultimate endeavor here is to click the thumbnail and animate the mask to reveal the entire thumb.

I nested the showPictures function so it could have a reference to the masks, which is not optimal, so if anyone could help me see a better way to do this I'd really appreciate it.

package

```
public class MiniGallery extends Sprite
{
        //create($columns:int, $rows:int, $xSpacing:int, $ySpacing:int, $xPadding:int, $yPadding:int)

        private var imagePoints:Array = grid.create(8, 1, 100, 0, 10.5, 15);
        private var fadeTween:*
        private var imageText:TextField = new TextField();
        private var imageLoader:Loader;                                 
        private var xml:XML;                                                
        private var xmlList:XMLList;                                    
        private var xmlLoader:URLLoader 
        private var i:int
        private var _mask:SimpleRectangle;
        private var _sprite:Sprite;



    public function MiniGallery()
    {
        flash.system.Security.allowDomain("*")  
        var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();              
        xmlLoader.load (new URLRequest("data/images.xml")); 
        xmlLoader.addEventListener (Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded); 

    }

        private function xmlLoaded (event:Event):void                   
        {
            xml = XML(event.target.data);                       
            xmlList = xml.children();                           
                trace('xmlList is: ' + xmlList)
            for (i = 0; i < xmlList.length(); i++)      
            {
                imageLoader = new Loader();
                imageLoader.load (new URLRequest(xmlList[i].attribute("thumb")));   
                createBoxes ();
            }
        }


            private function createBoxes ():void
            {
                for (var j:int = 0; j < 1; j++)

                {

                    imageLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showPicture) 
                    imageLoader.x = imagePoints[i].x;                   
                    imageLoader.y = imagePoints[i].y - 36;
                    _mask = new SimpleRectangle(88,50, 0x000000, 0x000000, 0, 1);
                    _mask.name = xmlList[i].toString();
                    imageLoader.name = xmlList[i].attribute("source");
                    trace('imageLoader name is ' + imageLoader.name)
                    _mask.x = imagePoints[i].x
                    _mask.y = imagePoints[i].y
                    imageLoader.mask = _mask;
                    trace('mask name is ' + _mask.name)
                    addChild (imageLoader);
                    _sprite = new Sprite
                    _sprite.addChild(imageLoader)
                    addChild(_sprite)
                    _sprite.addChild(_mask)


                }


        function showPicture (event:MouseEvent):void
        { 


            TweenLite.to(_mask, 3, {scaleY:-40, ease:Quad.easeOut});





        }

    }


}
```

This traces out the XmlList correctly which stackOverflow wont show, and this:

xmlList is:

```
<image source="m1" thumb="thumbnails/dj051.jpg">mask1</image>
<image source="m2" thumb="thumbnails/dj052.jpg">mask2</image>
<image source="m3" thumb="thumbnails/dj053.jpg">mask3</image>
<image source="m4" thumb="thumbnails/dj054.jpg">mask4</image>
<image source="m5" thumb="thumbnails/dj055.jpg">mask5</image>
<image source="m6" thumb="thumbnails/dj056.jpg">mask6</image>
<image source="m7" thumb="thumbnails/dj057.jpg">mask7</image>
<image source="m8" thumb="thumbnails/dj058.jpg">mask8</image>
```

imageLoader name is m1
mask name is mask1
imageLoader name is m2
mask name is mask2
imageLoader name is m3
mask name is mask3
imageLoader name is m4
mask name is mask4
imageLoader name is m5
mask name is mask5
imageLoader name is m6
mask name is mask6
imageLoader name is m7
mask name is mask7
imageLoader name is m8
mask name is mask8

Answer (score 0):

I think you should draw all the rectangles of all the masks you need into one graphic context of one Sprite or shape and tha attach this on Display object as mask. A sprite can only have one single mask.